# how to enable auto scaling with Celery multi workers?

Tags: python, celery

The command `celery worker -A proj --autoscale=10,1 --loglevel=info` starts workers with auto scaling.

When creating workers with multi,

```
me@mypc:~/projects/x$ celery multi start myworker --autoscale=10,1
celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Starting nodes...
    > myworker@mypc: OK

me@mypc:~/projects/kate$ celery multi show myworker
/home/me/.virtualenvs/kate/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker --detach -n myworker@mypc --pidfile=myworker.pid --logfile=myworker%I.log --executable=/home/me/.virtualenvs/x/bin/python2.7
```

How do I enable multi to autoscale?

Answer (score 6):

Autoscaling will start new processes when the work load increases. In your case you have set the min number to 1, so you will only see 1 process, unless you start putting more tasks onto your queues. You can change the way the autoscaler works. See the link below for more details:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoscaling

Comment: the question is specifically about celery multi.

Comment: [Autoscaling has been removed as of celery 4.0](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4003)

Comment: @Greg I don't think it has, there is quite a bit of confusion in that ticket but it appears it's still available, but might have some bugs with it.

Comment: lots of comments regarding whether autoscale removed, whether autoscale is broken, and requests to add tests