# celery autoscaling - determine optimum number of pool processes required

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I need to determine the best possible combination of minimum and a maximum number of pool processes. Is there a way of testing and getting the optimum values?
I'm using `rabbitmq` as a broker and this process is running on a machine with 8 cores

Comment: You can refer to these two answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898311/celery-difference-between-concurrency-workers-and-autoscaling and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989636/how-to-enable-auto-scaling-with-celery-multi-workers